# Serving a page with multiple database's

Tags: python, database, sqlalchemy, flask

What i have: multiple identical databses and a SQL-Alchemy setup.

What I need to achieve: a single "Flask" function able to query all the databses. All other functions need to access only one of the databases.

The DB's already exist and I am loading data from them.

Initially I was only using the SQL-Alchemy abstraction layer, without any Flask model. This is how the code looked like:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object('myflaskapp.config.settings')
metadata = None

def connect_db():
    engine = create_engine(app.config['DATABASE_URI'])
    global metadata
    metadata = MetaData(bind=engine)
    return engine.connect()

@app.before_request
    def before_request():
    g.db = connect_db()

@app.after_request
    def after_request(response):
    close_connection()
    return response
```

being DATABASE_URI declared in settings.py. I guess doesn't matter, however the underlying DB is a Mysql server and DATABASE_URI looks like:

```
DATABASE_URI = 'mysql://' + dbuser + ':' + dbpass + '@' + dbhost + '/' +dbname
```

The above code allows me to write something like this:

```
myTable = Table('branch', metadata, autoload=True)
myBranch = select([myTable])
```

which is quite handy. This approach works just fine unless I have to deal with more than one DB. To be more precise I'd like to show (from within the same function) data belonging to multiple DB's that have exactly the same structure. Meaning that the same query can be succesfully run againsy any DB. In pseudo code:

```
@app.route('/summary')
def summary():
     ....
     allData = []
     for db in all_of_my_dbs:
         allData.append(db.query())
     ....
sendToTemplate(allData)
```

Is it something doable? Is it feasable?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's definitely [possible](http://pythonhosted.org/Flask-SQLAlchemy/binds.html).

Try adding something like this to your settings file

```
SQLALCHEMY_BINDS = {
    'users':        'mysqldb://localhost/users',
    'appmeta':      'sqlite:////path/to/appmeta.db'
}
```

**Edit**

So here is a working copy/paste example

```
from flask import Flask
from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)
app.debug = True

databases = {
    'sqlite1': 'sqlite:///sqlite1.db',
    'sqlite2': 'sqlite:///sqlite2.db'
}
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_BINDS'] = databases
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class Thing(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "sqlite1"
    thing_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    thing_val = db.Column(db.String(40))

    def __init__(self, thing_val):
        self.thing_val = thing_val

class Thing2(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "sqlite2"
    thing_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    thing_val = db.Column(db.String(40))

    def __init__(self, thing_val):
        self.thing_val = thing_val


if __name__ == "__main__":

    db.create_all()
    t1 = Thing("test1")
    t2 = Thing2("test2")

    db.session.add(t1)
    db.session.add(t2)
    db.session.commit()

    t1 = Thing.query.filter_by(thing_id=1).first()
    t2 = Thing2.query.filter_by(thing_id=1).first()

    print t1.thing_val
    print t2.thing_val
```

Comment: I had already seen that link, for reasons that now escape me I thought it didn't suite my needs. Will give a try tomorrow. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Looks like it's not what I need. Or at least I am not able to see how to tie the hints contained in that page to what I need.

Comment: @DiMizioRiziero if you still haven't figured out by the time I get home from work. I'll see if I can find a working example, we're not allowed to have sqlalchemy at work =|.

Comment: That would be great. I'll keep looking into it and update if I come across anything useful.

Comment: I am triong to get your example to work. Why do you assign the bindname to the __tablename__ var? I guess __tablename__ should be the same for both the Thing1 and Thing2 and the var __bind_key has come from SQLALCHEMY_BINDS. Thank you for your time, mui appreciated

Comment: what kind of job prohibits a python library?

Comment: I guess the section "Using Reflection with Declarative" at this link http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/orm/extensions/declarative.html is what I need.

Answer (score 0):

First I would like to remark a couple of things regarding my very own situation. The two tables have the same name, same DDL but belong to different schema's/database's.

```
from flask import Flask
from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)

databases = {
    'sqlite1': 'sqlite:///sqlite1.db',
    'sqlite2': 'sqlite:///sqlite2.db'
}

app.config['SQLALCHEMY_BINDS'] = databases
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class Thing(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "mytable"
    __bind_key__ = 'sqlite1'
    thing_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    thing_val = db.Column(db.String(40))

    def __init__(self, thing_val):
        self.thing_val = thing_val


if __name__ == "__main__":

    t1 = Thing.query.filter_by(thing_id=1).first()
    print t1.name
```

The moment I add a second Class named Thing2 just after the first class definition everything breakes. I.e.:

```
class Thing(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "mytable"
    __bind_key__ = 'sqlite1'
    thing_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    thing_val = db.Column(db.String(40))

    def __init__(self, thing_val):
        self.thing_val = thing_val


class Thing2(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "mytable"
    __bind_key__ = 'sqlite2'
    thing_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    thing_val = db.Column(db.String(40))

    def __init__(self, thing_val):
        self.thing_val = thing_val
```

The above code breaks with this error:

**InvalidRequestError: Table 'mytable' is already defined for this MetaData instance.  Specify 'extend_existing=True' to redefine options and columns on an existing Table object.**

So the framework doesn't seem to be able to distinguish between the two of them.

Answer (score 0):

apparently there is a bug on that issue -https://github.com/mitsuhiko/flask-sqlalchemy/pull/222 so the problem is that the bind key must be unique and can be used only for one class (at least for now),so you could still have multiple databases but each database can have only one table or a class but it does appear to have a huge overhead if you many tables still this is just a workaround at least for now...

here is the reference for "Binds" -http://flask-sqlalchemy.pocoo.org/2.0/binds/#binds

Below is the configuration:

SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = 'sqlite://///main.db'

SQLALCHEMY_BINDS= {
'table1':'sqlite://///DB1.db',
'table2':'sqlite://///DB2.db',
}

and below is the model:

class table1(db.Model):

```
__tablename__ = "table1"
__bind_key__='table1'
```

class table2(db.Model):

```
__tablename__ = "table2"
__bind_key__='table2'
```